# Prevent pointer from being passed as array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

So while it is common/typical to accept an [array that has decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) like the following

```
#include <iostream>

void example(int* data)
{
    std::cout << data[0] << ' ' << data[1] << ' ' << data[2] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int data[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    example(data);
}
```

I noticed that you can also seemingly do the opposite. Namely you can pass a pointer that will undecay(?) back to an array

```
#include <iostream>

void example(int data[3])
{
    std::cout << data[0] << ' ' << data[1] << ' ' << data[2] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int data[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    example(data);
    example(nullptr);  // Is this legal? Can I prevent this?
}
```

Note that the `data` argument of `example` has changed from `int*` to `int[3]` yet I am still able to pass `nullptr`. Changing the argument to `std::array<int, 3>` will obviously prevent this, but I'm curious if this implicit conversion is described by the standard? There is a lot of commentary on "array to pointer" implicit conversion, but this seems to be the other way around.

Comment: i wouldn't call it "common/typical". Of course that depends on what kind of code you are used to

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I deal with code ranging from "written yesterday" back to "written 2 decades ago" so I agree it depends on a lot on the codebase, but in general that is (or was?) a very common idiom to see around.

Comment: `void example(int* data, int size)` would be more common, but it is C-like code anyway, and not really C++.

Comment: Re: `example(nullptr);`: "_Is this legal?_" - Yes. "_Can I prevent it_" - Yes, by adding a deleted overload: : `void example(std::nullptr_t) = delete;`

Comment: Here's a semi-ugly template version of [`example()`](https://godbolt.org/z/sbccj1jWb) to make it accept a `const int[]` of any valid size.. `nullptr` is also rejected of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact,

```
void example(int data[3])
```

is

```
void example(int data[])
```

or

```
void example(int* data)
```

You need

```
void example(/*const*/ int (&data)[3])
```

to have array reference, (and so rejecting pointer or array of different size).

Answer (score 5):

When you have

```
void example(int data[3])
```

that array itself decays to a pointer so the function is actually

```
void example(int* data)
```

which is why you can still pass `nullptr` to the function.  The relevant paragraph for this is [[dcl.fct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#5)

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. The type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is determined from its own parameter-declaration ([dcl.decl]). After determining the type of each parameter, **any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”.** [...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>